# How to use an interface with props.children and other property types?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am using Next.js and Typescript.

I have a layout component that using the following interface:

```js
export interface AuxProps {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  pageTitle: 'string';
}
```

The component is here:

```js
const Page = (props: AuxProps): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <div className="whole-page">
      <div className="sidenav">
        <SideNav />
      </div>
      <div className="main">
        <Header pageTitle={props.pageTitle} />
        <div className={styles.bodySection}>{props.children}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

However, when i want to use the `pageTitle` prop in another component, I get the error: `Type '"Home"' is not assignable to type '"string"'.`

But `Home` is not a type, its the value provided to the prop.

Here is how I am using it:

```js
 let title: AuxProps = {
    pageTitle: 'Home',
  };


... inside the component ...

<Page pageTitle={title.pageTitle}>

...
```

I looked on SO, and i couldn't find any examples of when props.childen is being used with other property values. Is that an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your interface it should be `string` instead of `'string'` because `'string'` here is string value like any other value `'test','test2'` and you need `string` as a type.So using the code below should fix your issue

```
export interface AuxProps {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  pageTitle: string;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is a very easy mistake to make for people who are new to TS. I am surprised that the IDE didn't give the error message on the interface.

Comment: its not an error on interface if you declare `pageTitle:'string'` you can still assign `'string'` to pageTitle like `pageTitle='string'` but that's the only value you can assign. For example if you want to restrict `pageTitle` to `Home/User` only then you can do like `pageTitle:'Home'|'User'`

Comment: I see, it becomes a literal type. Good point. Thank you.